# Estimate User's uptime

Tags: django, django-users

It is very important for me to monitor my users. In specific, I am interested to know how long time they are logged in to the site. So I want to estimate, for each user, the uptime %, that means:

[image: Uptime % Formula]

My first approach then, was to calculate these two values.

I already have in the database the historical online time for each user, but I can't figure out how to get the historical online time of the server. I was thinking in adding a constant to the database and auto update it when the server is running but I am not sure how to this. **Note that the server is not always running so I can't just save an initial datetime to get its historical online time.**

Maybe there is a different way to estimate the uptime % that doesn't require to calculate these two values, so if you have any alternative solution, I would be glad to hear it also.

Comment: Do you have any server logs? Apache and nginx will write access logs with timestamps for any incoming HTTP requests. You could use those to calculate historical uptime for your server.

Comment: @HåkenLid Thanks! First of all I am using Django. When I wrote the question the title specified that this was a Django related problem but Sayse erased it, don't know why. 

I couldn't find a log with that information in Django, but even if I could, the timestamps of the request don't give enough information to know when the server was running and when not (unless you have a very big traffic and the requests don't stop since the server is running until it closes).

Comment: Depends on what kind of website you are running. Most sites that uses a public domain name will get traffic from various webcrawlers and bots even when there's no human visitors. If it's an intranet or something like that, there might be gaps in the log even when the server is up.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your idea gave me a clue for a possible solution.. I will keep working on this and if I manage to solve it I will edit my question.